# water pump problems

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, hydraulics

I am presently facing a problem in water plant .

In a tank there are four pump placed at equal distance named A B C D .in this arrangement A and D  positioned  at near corner of the tank . I started A B C  pump at a same time also D kept for stand by purpose . 
  In this arrangement the pump A gives less delivery than the other B C pumps. Where as all pump having same specification.

Pump locating at corner of tank disturb the delivery

Comment: All pipes same size? Do inlets have bell mouths?

Comment: All pipes same size ,yes elbow joint in all pump inlet

Comment: I did not ask about elbow joints....

Comment: Try starting B C and D at the same time and see if D performs the same as A did. Do the pumps have the same wet ends? Do the motors have the same amperage?

Comment: Have you reviewed the pump curve for total projected flow against inlet pipe velocity? Is the common suction pipe size for all four pumps starving the capacity of the third pump?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE, Vignesh. I think your question misses the end - I am not able to currently figure out what the actual problem is. Also, would you please take the time to write a more descriptive title.

Comment: I suspect that the piping on the pressure pipe is different between the pumps, can you show a picture or diagram?

Comment: All inlets have bell mouths